# MySQL setting lower_case_table_names=2 prevents service from starting

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to get MySQL running locally on Windows 10 for development. I need upper and lower case letters in my table names.

I can see that when running MySQL in Windows it is advised to set lower_case_table_names=2 in my.ini.

When I try this the MySQL Windows service starts and then immediately stops. It doesn't appear to record any event to the event log when it does this.

If I remove the line the service starts fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Different recommendations are told by [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names). Did you read it?

Comment: According to the Workbench IDE that comes with MySQL "Should be set to 2 if you are using a case-insensitive file system" Is NTFS not a case-insensitive file system?

Comment: Also... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html "Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and lower_case_table_names=2 on Windows. "

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems even oracle can't agree on how the setting should be set.

I've turned to using MariaDB on my Synology drive instead which took 5 mins to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names), my experience with the system variable `lower_case_table_names` is that on Windows, *only* `1`, `stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive` is supported. On Linux it's forced to `0`, `stored as specified and comparisons are case-sensitive`.

Dunno what happens on MaxOS.